# How do I know if a rewritten rule was applied?

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting

I defined a custom post type with rewrite rule:

```
    register_post_type('balls', [
        'labels' => [
            'name' => 'balls',
            'singular_name' => 'balls',
            'add_new' => 'new',
            'add_new_item' => 'new',
            'parent_item_colon' => ''
        ],
        'taxonomies' => ['category'],
        'menu_position' => 4,
        'public' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'supports' => ['title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'],
        'rewrite' => [
            'slug' => 'ballinfo'
        ]
    ]);
```

now how do I know if a site was called with `/ballinfo` or not? How do I know if my rewrite rule was matched and used?

Comment: Go to `wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=balls` and mouseover the "View" link of any post, and see if the permalink has `/ballinfo/{slug}`. If yes, the rewrite rule is being applied. Then visit the permalink and if you see the proper post/content, the rewrite rule works properly. If not, visit the permalink settings page to flush the rewrite rules.

Comment: If you meant by programmatically, you can get the rewrite rule that matches the requested URL via [`WP::$matched_rule`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.8/src/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L61).

Comment: yes, programmatically. Sadly WP::$matched_rule causes fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: WP::$matched_rule.

Comment: Use either `global $wp; echo $wp->matched_rule;` or `echo $GLOBALS['wp']->matched_rule;`

Comment: There's probably an API function to accomplish what you are trying to do, like `is_singular( 'balls' );`, but you have not described the problem you are trying to solve or given any details, like where and when you are trying to do this.

Comment: @SallyCJ this: $GLOBALS['wp']->matched_rule seems to work, could you post it?

Comment: @JohnSmith, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I'm not very sure of what you're trying to achieve, but I hope this answer can help. :)***

1. With the way your custom post type is being registered, WordPress will create custom rewrite rules such as below for the CPT's single post pages:

   ```
   RegEx: ballinfo/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$
   Query: index.php?balls=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]
   ```
2. So for the following question:

   > how do I know if a site was called with `/ballinfo` or not

   When the single page of a `balls` post is visited, the URL would have `/ballinfo/` as in `example.com/ballinfo/an-example-balls-post`.

   Now to programmatically check if the URL contains `/ballinfo/`, you can check if the [`$request`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.8/src/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L53) property of the global `WP` class instance starts with a `ballinfo/` like so:

   ```
   global $wp;
   if ( preg_match( '#^ballinfo/#', $wp->request ) ) {
       echo 'Site was called with the /ballinfo<br>';
   }
   echo '$wp->request is ' . $wp->request . '<br>';
   ```
3. And for the following question:

   > How do I know if my rewrite rule was matched and used?

   You can match the rule (RegEx) with the one in the [`$matched_rule`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.8/src/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L61) property of the global `WP` class instance.

   For example, for the single `balls` post pages, where the rule uses the RegEx pattern as in point #1 in this answer, try this:

   ```
   global $wp;
   if ( 'ballinfo/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$' === $wp->matched_rule ) {
       echo 'Yay, my rewrite rule was matched!<br>';
   } else {
       echo 'Not matched. $wp->matched_rule is ' . $wp->matched_rule . '<br>';
   }
   ```

And you may already know this, but if you just wanted to check if the requested URL is for a CPT post/archive/etc., you can use `is_singular()`, `is_post_type_archive()`, and other appropriate WordPress [conditional functions/tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/).